# Django: Pillow seems to install but is not showing in pip freeze

Tags: python, django

I'm having problems installing Pillow in a venv on AWS Linux.  Pillow seems to install correctly but pip freeze doesn't list it and Django runserver fails claiming that PIL is missing.  The following console output shows the problem:

```
[root@ip-172-31-25-228 ichiba]# source venv/bin/activate
(venv) [root@ip-172-31-25-228 ichiba]# pip freeze
asgiref==3.2.10
Django==3.1.1
django-bootstrap-form==3.4
django-crispy-forms==1.9.2
django-filter==2.3.0
django-rest-framework==0.1.0
djangorestframework==3.11.1
pytz==2020.1
sqlparse==0.3.1
(venv) [root@ip-172-31-25-228 ichiba]# pip install Pillow
Collecting Pillow
  Using cached Pillow-7.2.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (2.2 MB)
Installing collected packages: Pillow
Successfully installed Pillow-7.2.0
(venv) [root@ip-172-31-25-228 ichiba]# pip freeze
asgiref==3.2.10
Django==3.1.1
django-bootstrap-form==3.4
django-crispy-forms==1.9.2
django-filter==2.3.0
django-rest-framework==0.1.0
djangorestframework==3.11.1
pytz==2020.1
sqlparse==0.3.1
(venv) [root@ip-172-31-25-228 ichiba]#
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks and regards...Paul

Comment: Have you tried ```pip install pillow``` with lowercase pillow?

Comment: It seems that Pillow is being installed into ```lib64/python3.6/dist-packages``` rather than ```lib64/python3.6/dist-packages```.  I did:

```cp -R lib64/python3.6/dist-packages/* lib/python3.6/dist-packages``` and pip freeze now shows pillow and Django starts.

Doesn't seem like a real fix.

Comment: Hi Andrey, Just noticed your question.  I think I did but I'll try again.

Comment: Hi @AndreyBorzenko,  I tried ```pip install pillow``` but it didn't fix the problem.  The only fix I can work our is to copy the files from one lib to the other as described above.